# How do I make the navbar links appear horizontally instead of stacked vertically on top of eachother?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for a code bootcamp, and the navbar is supposed to have a: Home, About, Sites, Contact and Weather. I have them appearing on the navbar but I don't know how to get them to appear how I want. Currently they are all on the left side of the Navbar but stacked vertically above one another.

[Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ0Yo.png)

I've tried messing with the Navbar HTML but haven't been able to figure it out and I'm wondering if it's a HTML thing or is it something I need to do in CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- Additional CSS must be placed after Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Open+Sans" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.scss" />
    <title>Nucamp: A Better Way To Camp</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 align-self-center">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>Nucamp</h1>
                    <h2>a better way to camp</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-2 mt-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg text-white text-nowrap" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                        data-bs-target="#reserveModal">
                        Reserve Campsite
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark sticky-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" height="30" width="30" /></a>
    
            <!-- Add the navbar-nav class to the <ul> element -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house fa-lg"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-info fa-lg"></i> About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-list fa-lg"></i> Sites</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card fa-lg"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    
            <!-- Weather information -->
            <div id="weather" class="d-flex align-items-center ms-3">
                <i id="weather-icon"></i>
                <span id="weather-temp"></span>
                <span id="weather-description" class="d-none d-lg-inline"></span>
            </div>
    
            <span class="navbar-text ms-auto">
                <a role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i> Login
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    
    

    <!-- login modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Login</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <form>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="mb-3 col-12">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="loginEmail">Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="loginEmail"
                                        placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3 col-12">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="loginPassword">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="loginPassword"
                                        placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-check mb-3">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                                        <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                        data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- reservation form modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="reserveModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Reserve a Campsite</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <form id="reserveForm" action="https://us-central1-nucamp-production.cloudfunctions.net/post/formdata" method="post">
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label for="numCampers" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Number of Campers</label>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <select name="numCampers" id="numCampers" class="form-control">
                                        <option>Select...</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <label for="date" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Date</label>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input type="date" id="date" name="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
                                        class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <button class="btn btn-dark" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- main content -->
    <main class="container">

        <!-- carousel -->
        <!-- carousel -->
<section class="row row-content">
    <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#homeCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#homeCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#homeCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
                <!-- Removed the div with the btn-group class and the Play button -->
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carouselButton">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-pause" id="faButton"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/breadcrumb-trail.jpg" alt="Breadcrumb Trail Campground" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Breadcrumb Trail Campground</h3>
                        <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Let Nucamp be your guide to this off-the-beaten-path, hike-in-only campground.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/react-lake.jpg" alt="React Lake Campground" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>React Lake Campground</h3>
                        <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Nestled in the foothills of the Chrome Mountains, this campground on the shores of the pristine React Lake is a favorite for fly fishers.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/chrome-river.jpg" alt="Chrome River Campground" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Chrome River Campground</h3>
                        <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Spend a few sunny days and starry nights beneath a canopy of old-growth firs at this enchanting spot by the Chrome River.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


        <!-- discover section -->
        <section class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 order-sm-last">
                <h2 class="text-sm-end">Discover & Review</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <img class="me-3 img-thumbnail" src="img/breadcrumb-trail-thumb.jpg" alt="Breadcrumb Trail" />
                    <div class="align-self-center">
                        <h3>Our Campsites</h3>
                        <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Explore our growing database of curated campsites and leave your
                            own reviews!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- feature section -->
        <section class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <h2>Featured Campsites</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="align-self-center">
                        <h3>React Lake Campground</h3>
                        <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Nestled in the foothills of the Chrome Mountains, this campground
                            on the shores of the pristine React Lake is a favorite for fly fishers.</p>
                    </div>
                    <img class="ms-3 img-thumbnail" src="img/react-lake-thumb.jpg" alt="React Lake" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- partner section -->
        <section class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 order-sm-last">
                <h2 class="text-sm-end">Our Community Partners</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <img class="me-3 img-thumbnail" src="img/bootstrap-thumb.png" alt="Bootstrap Outfitters" />
                    <div class="align-self-center">
                        <h3>Bootstrap Outfitters</h3>
                        <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Bootstrap Outfitters supplies you with gear you need at prices you
                            can't beat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="row row-content align-items-start review-section mb-3">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 order-sm-first">
                <h2 class="text-sm-end">What Are Happy Campers Saying?</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col ms-lg-5">
                <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="img/happy-campers.jpg" alt="picture of two happy campers">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h3>So Worth It!</h3>
                <p>"We had a blast as we embarked on a wild adventure amidst nature's embrace, where s'mores and laughter under starlit skies became our daily ritual, creating memories that will last us forever."</p>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
                <button class="campsite-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#reserveModal">Reserve Campsite</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>

    <!-- footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 offset-1">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-5 text-center">
                    <h5>Social</h5>
                    <a href="http://instagram.com/"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-xl"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://facebook.com/"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-xl"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-xl"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa-brands fa-youtube fa-xl"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-phone fa-lg text-primary"></i> 1-206-555-1234<br />
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope fa-lg text-primary"></i> campsites@nucamp.co
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript plugins -->
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js" type="module"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">

<nav>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house fa-lg"></i> Home</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-info fa-lg"></i> About</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-list fa-lg"></i> Sites</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card fa-lg"></i> Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
```

```
<div class="header">
<a href="" >Home</a>
<a href="">About us</a>
<a href="">Sites</a>
<a href="">Contact us</a>
<a href="">weather</a>
</div>

<!-- then apply margin, padding as per your required to design  -->

</body>
</html>
```